# Find expected value given CDF

Tags: probability

[image]

X is a random variable, but the probability at $x=0$ does not factor into expected value of X because it is zero. Hence, I am getting
$E[X] = \int_2^3 x\cdot \frac{x-1}{2} dx = 1.91$, but answer is 1.25. Am I missing something?

Comment: The probability at $x = 0$ should be included as the circle is filled in at $(0, 0.5)$.

Comment: yes but when calculating $E[X]$, it contributes $0\cdot P(X=0) = 0$

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expected value is $\mathbb E[X]=\int_{\mathbb R}x f_X(x)\,dx$ where $f_X(x)$ is a pdf, not cdf. To find pdf of absolutely continuous component if $X$, take derivative $\left(\frac{x-1}{2}\right)'=\frac12$, so 
$$
\mathbb E[X] = 0\cdot \mathbb P(X=0) + \int_2^3 x\cdot\frac12 \, dx. 
$$

Note that the other way is to use ($X\geq 0$)
$$
\mathbb E[X] = \int_0^\infty (1-F_X(x)) \,dx
$$
which equals to the area above cdf and below $1$, right from zero.

Comment: I knew it was gonna be a dumb mistake haha thanks.

Comment: Sure, I had no doubt that you knew this. Ordinary misprint.